# How to make a react component start scrolling(y-axis) only after the end of the entire component has been reached within the broser?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, overflow, tailwind-css

This concept is completely new to me. Am working on a simple project and the client asked that I make the component(a vertical list with list items stacked on one another) be scrollable only after I have reached the end of the component on the bottom of the entire screen, if that makes sense.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a sample working code highlighting the issue you're having.

Comment: Well, I did nothing so far it's just a basic component that has overflow-y overflow-scroll but the thing I am curious about is how would I go about making it scroll after the component reaches its end by scrolling the entire page first, if that makes sense.